# Appium IOS Native app find element by label

Tags: java, ios, appium

Can we find an ios native application button by it's label using appium ?
Using Accessiblity Inspector, only labels can be found.
We do not have the source of the app that we seek automate, it's already installed.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unstead of IOSDriver ,we were using RemoteWebDriver, wich lacks many features.
Now, we're using Accessibility ID.

Comment: how do you use ID with remotewebdriver?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the following alternatives to the accessibility inspector:

1. [Appium iOS Inspector](https://github.com/mykola-mokhnach/Appium-iOS-Inspector#appium-ios-inspector)

   [image]
2. [Appium Desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop#appium-desktop)

   [image]
3. [Appium Studio](https://experitest.com/mobile-test-automation/appium-studio/)

   [image]

---

Also be aware that you can always stick to the label attribute by using [XPath Selector](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-xpath-selector) like:

```
//*[@label='your label text here']
```